# Regex for password least one character from three 3 categories

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that will check: contain at least one (1) character from three (4) of the following categories:

- Uppercase letter (A-Z)
- Lowercase letter (a-z)
- Digit (0-9)
- Special character (~`!@#$%^&*()+=_-{}[]\|:;”’?/<>,.)

It is not mandatory to have from all 4 categories, is ok at least from 3 categories

Comment: Why you have to do it with a regex? Is this part of the requirement?

Comment: Check it https://regex101.com/r/8Vqpiy/6

Comment: "character from three (3)" you have four categories. Do you actually mean four?

Comment: at least 1 character from 4 category, but min 3 categories must be

Comment: I think this point (at lesat 3 out of 4) should be emphasised more (at lest one answer already missed it). And again why it has to be regex? (would be much simpler without regex)

Comment: We use javax validation annotation, an it require a regexp

Comment: @ Wiktor: Linked question has no answer that OP is really looking for. OP needs a pure regex that works for him as he needs the regex in validation annotation. But in linked question no answer provides that. You should reopen the question and be careful while marking a post as duplicate going ahead.

Answer (score 1):

As you want out of four conditions if any three conditions are met, then it should accept the password, you will need look ahead with all different permutations/combinations. You can use this regex,

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])(?=.*[A-Z\d])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])(?=.*[a-z\d])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\|:;”’?\/<>,.-])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])).*$
```

As you can see the regex has become too large to explain, let me just brief you with the concept applied here.

As there are four character sets, out of which if password contains at least one char out of any three, then you accept, hence you need to do a look ahead to check for two character sets, and then third character set can be combined with remaining two to check if at least one character is from the remaining one. And apply this logic with all such permutation and alternate all the cases. Let me take one alternation to explain you with sample. Like this,

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d~`!@#$%^&*()+=_{}\[\]\:;”’?\/<>,.-])
```

Here it checks if password contains a lower case, an upper case, then in remaining sets which is number and special characters can be combined as we just need any one character to be matching in number or special character set.

Same logic can be applied with different formation of character sets and together put into alternation to match any combination, to give you the validity of password.

**[Here is a working online demo](https://regex101.com/r/yy8zhk/2)**

I have taken various samples to illustrate that password will not match if it is only belonging to two character sets and it will start to match just with the inclusion of one character from the remaining character set.

Hope this helps. Let me know in case you have any queries.

Comment: "abcAB1234" should be valid, can be min from 3 categories

Comment: @jahoza: Ok your this requirement wasn't clear from your post. Let me modify the regex.